# Show a matrix is a linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, linear-transformations, multilinear-algebra, mathematica

So I know I need to multiply my transformations by (1,0) and (0,1) but I’m unsure how to get the transformations as if I multiply just by the given matrix I get the same answer please help. 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you having trouble showing that $R$ is represented by that matrix, or that it's linear?

Comment: Thank you I’m not exactly sure I want to prove it’s an isomorphism but I’m struggling to prove it’s a linear transformation in order to do this I’m confusing myself 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear transformation is a function, L, from a vector space to a vector space such that, for any numbers, a and b, and vectors, u and v, L(au+ bv)= aL(u)+ bL(v).

Here L is the matrix multiplication, $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$

Let $u=\begin{bmatrix}m \\ n\end{bmatrix}$ and $v= \begin{bmatrix}p \\ q \end{bmatrix}$.

$L(au+ bv)= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}am+ bp \\ an+ bq\end{bmatrix}$
$= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{am+ bp}{2}- \frac{\sqrt{3}(an+ bq)}{3} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}(am+ bq)}{2}+ \frac{am+ bp}{2}\end{bmatrix}$

While $aL(u)+ bL(v)= a\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}m \\ n\end{bmatrix}+ b\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p\\ q\end{bmatrix}$
$= a\begin{bmatrix}\frac{m}{2}- \frac{\sqrt{2}m}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}m}{2}+ \frac{n}{2}\end{bmatrix}$+ b\begin{bmatrix}\frac{p}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}q}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}p}{2}+ \frac{q}{2}\end{bmatrix}$

Do you see that those are the same?

Comment: I do yes! Could I do this with u and v being numbers not letters would I still get the same idea?